# mysql randomly stopped working

Tags: mysql, crash, debian

hi my mysql was working i did nothing on it then today when i went to login to multicraft it gave me error 500 which means theres an issue with mysql and i tried to do $service mysql restart it didnt work so i did $service mysql status and i got this error

> ● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
>
> > > Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
> > >       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-01-27 16:39:39 CET; 24min >ago
> > >       Process: 27320 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> > >       Process: 28147 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, >status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Jan 27 16:39:39 ns3317389.ip-37-59-14.eu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and >sto...
>   Jan 27 16:39:39 ns3317389.ip-37-59-14.eu mysql[28147]: /etc/init.d/mysql: >ERROR:...
>   Jan 27 16:39:39 ns3317389.ip-37-59-14.eu systemd[1]: mysql.service: control >proc...
>   Jan 27 16:39:39 ns3317389.ip-37-59-14.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start >...
>   Jan 27 16:39:39 ns3317389.ip-37-59-14.eu systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered >...
>   Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Answer (score 0):

1. look in your /var/log/mysql/*.log logs
2. try to start mysql on the commandline

Example: 
as root user: mysqld --console